# Why is 'EINTR' undeclared?

Tags: c, unix, io

I included `<error.h>`.

```
#include <error.h>
#include <unistd.h>

ssize_t rio_readn(int fd, void *buf, size_t n)
{
    size_t nleft = n;
    char *rbuf = buf;
    while(nleft > 0)
    {
        int nread = read(fd, rbuf, nleft);
        if(nread < 0)
        {
            if(error == EINTR)
                nread = 0;
            else
                return -1;
        }
        else if(nread == 0)
            break;
        nleft -= nread;
        rbuf += nread;
    }
    return n - nleft;
}
```

Comment: You are aware `error` is a function?

Comment: In general, please don't include line numbers in code — it makes it hard to copy and compile.  If you include compiler error messages with line numbers, it can be a good idea to indicate which line in the code belongs to which error, but you haven't got the error messages here.

Comment: i'm sorry, i write `error == EINTR`, it should be 'errorno == EINTR'

Comment: @Wonter Er, I'm pretty sure it should be `errno`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're missing the declaration for `EINTR` because `<error.h>` has no relation to `<errno.h>`, which is where `EINTR` is declared.  And the error variable is `errno` and not `error`, too.